# Como Retornar Erro de chave Primária já existente em PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Boa tarde.

Como retornar um erro quando há uma tentativa de inserção de linha em uma tabela, e a chave primária já existir? Por padrão, o banco de dados não insere a linha. Como mostrar esse erro como "Item já existente"?

Segue parte do cógido:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'datalin');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$inclui="INSERT INTO DTC (DTC_CDRDES,DTC_CGC,DTC_TIPDOC,DTC_NUMNFC,DTC_QTDVOL,DTC_DATREC,DTC_PROCES,DTC_FORNEC) VALUES ('$CDRDES','$CNPJ','$TipDoc','$NumNFC','$QTDVol','$DataRec','$proces','$FORNEC')";

mysqli_query($mysqli,$inclui);

if($inclui):
    echo "<script>
                alert('Usuario Incluido com sucusso. :D');
                window.location='index.php';
        </script>";
else:
    echo "<script>
            alert('Infelizmente não foi possível excluir. :C');
            window.location='index.php';
        </script>";
endif;//echo "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!<br>Agradecemos a atenção.";

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a função [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Aproveito para corrigir um erro de lógica do seu código, seu `if($inclui)` sempre vai dar true.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO DTC (DTC_CDRDES,DTC_CGC,DTC_TIPDOC,DTC_NUMNFC,DTC_QTDVOL,DTC_DATREC,DTC_PROCES,DTC_FORNEC) VALUES ('$CDRDES','$CNPJ','$TipDoc','$NumNFC','$QTDVol','$DataRec','$proces','$FORNEC')";

// mysqli_query retorna false se falhar
$sucesso = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

if(!$sucesso) {
    echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Funcionou colocando if($sucesso) sem o "!".

Comment: O `!` é uma negação. Sem isso, vai entrar no `if` quando a query executar sem problemas. Com a exclamação, só entra quando der problema (que pode ser violação de chave primária, precisa olhar a mensagem de erro pra ter certeza).